# Best way to encode a variable number of points in a 2D space as features

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, embeddings

I am presented with this problem: given a set of points (the number can vary, and their identity is not fixed across observations) distributed in a bounded 2D space (say $x \in [0,1]$, $y \in [0,1]$), predict a specific numerical value or class.

So, each observation is this **collection** of points. There is no rotational or translational invariance. To make a trivial example, think about the task of predicting the correlation coefficient from a given scatterplot (of course, my problem is way less trivial!). What could be a meaningful encoding of such information?

I considered dividing the space into small squares and then performing some density estimation (dividing by the total number of points). This will enforce the same structure to all data points. Is there anything more elegant? Possible alternatives?

Comment: i am very interested to see what people have to say about this. One thing that I tried (because I wanted adjustable features) was to have $P$ neural networks defined on the input space. I would then define each feature as the average value of the neural network evaluated at all the input points (which is just 1 number no matter the number of input points, P times).

Comment: What can you tell us about the nature of this "specific numerical value"?  Surely there are some restrictions on the possibilities!

Comment: Thank you for asking @whuber ! What triggered my question is the prediction of the purity of cancer genomic data, so a fraction [0,1]. A sample can be projected in 2D space with log2R and AF on the two axes. There are tailored methods to analyze that, but I asked myself how I would attack this problem as a plain ML task.

The point is: what could be a generally good representation of an observation that takes such form? The form: a cloud of points, of variable size and no fixed point identity across observations, laying on a bounded $R^n$ space.

Comment: @JohnMadden I am not sure I entirely understood your strategy, but let's see if any answer pops out! This problem seems very trivial (and I am missing something) or uncommon. Another route I considered was to compare each point with all the others, using a distance metric, and then produce a matrix on which multiple global descriptors could be computed. No tests so far, only thoughts

Comment: @gianMa oh gosh, if it's trivial, I would love to see a reference discussing the what straightforward ways there are to solve it. That sure would make my life easier! Regarding the strategy you proposed, I think that could work if you're lucky, and whatever function you're evaluating on the distance matrix (maybe things like max eigval, mineigval, is that what you were thinking?) is indeed sufficient to predict what you want to.